# Custom button style with font style

Tags: android

Going to create android app, but as client requirement. 
I have to come up with custom style buttons and radio button.

Review the attached image[image]

1. How can I make the button and input field same as 'bullet point 1'.
2. How to use custom Arabic font style.
   (i.e https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo)

Comment: Custom buttons are achieved by making custom view for them. And there are already a lot of questions asked and answered on SO about using custom fonts.

Comment: provide the HTML and CSS of the buttons you have now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For bullet point 1, I would suggest you to use 9-patch images with stretchable area on top & bottom lines & keeping the circular arc on left/right edges of same radius.

***I can try to create same 9-patch image for you, but it's gonna take time :)*** (give me the color codes you want to use in)

2. For using Arabic fonts, please go through this Android Developer link **[Android Custom Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)**.

There are plenty of answers out there on how to use custom fonts, so you can easily find any one.

Here's how you can easily use that Cairo fonts types:

1. Download the Cairo font zip file, unzip it & put all **.ttf or .otf** files inside your **Project -> app -> src -> main -> res -> font folder**
2. Add below lines into your **styles.xml** file under res->values folder:

   ```
   <style name="cairo_semi_bold">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/Cairo-SemiBold</item>
   </style>

   <style name="cairo_light">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/Cairo-Light</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Now you can apply these fonts either in XML or in .java files like this:

   ```
   Typeface boldFont = getResources().getFont(R.font.cairo_semi_bold);
   textView1.setTypeface(boldFont);

   Typeface lightFont = getResources().getFont(R.font.cairo_light);
   textView2.setTypeface(lightFont);
   ```

Comment: can we use #00A79E or RGB:0,167,158. Also need to create same input field as point 1

Comment: For input-field, you'll need to create the required color in drawable png itself as it cannot be changed at run time. For font-face, it's very basic to change text color which you already know. I created the same drawable 9-patch image & it was working fine for fixed-height input-fields with variable width.

Answer (score 0):

for changing the font you can use Calligraphy library [here](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)! 
it's so easy to use

inside your xml `fontPath="your font"`

refer to the link for the complete guide